# File format not recognized yet compilation works for other code

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the most basic OpenCV program, **however I don't think the problem is OpenCV related**. Here is the code I am using to compile my file:

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` fine_name_my.png
```

Here is the `truncated` code for the same:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void readImage(const char* file, Mat& result) {
    Mat img = imread(file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    result = img;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check input arguments
    if(argc!=2) {
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <path_to_image>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // read and display the input image
    Mat bgrImg;
    readImage(argv[1], bgrImg);
    display("(a) inputImage", bgrImg);

    return 0;
}
```

While this fails to compile with the following error:

```
fine_name_my.png: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Another simple program like this, compiles perfectly:

```
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("/home/USER/Pictures/python.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("opencvtest",img);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Where have I mistaken?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to convert your `.png` file to `.jpg` file.

Comment: It appears your linker is trying to pull in your PNG as object code or an otherwise linkable archive.  Your code compiled fine. The link step is where the wheels fell off.

Comment: @Daniel Same error persists.

Comment: @WhozCraig Any solutions. I am really a novice in stuff like linker etc :(

Comment: Not really. I'm not a pkgconfig guy, and there is quite a bit going on in the expansions of that command line. It almost looks like there should be a `&& ./basename fine_name_my.png` rather than just `fine_name_my.png` as the tail of that command line. Again, not a pkgconfig guy. ymmv. If you remove the filename off the command, it should boringly create your executable, but not run your program. Does *that* at least work?

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually it does work. Just tested. I think I will just leave it at that!